# Chevening scholarships

Tags: graduate-school, masters

Chevening funded scholarships have a 'two years rule' which means you have to return to your home country for two years after finishing your masters degree in the UK. For anyone who has experience with this scholarship, or knows someone that has, I have a couple of questions:

- Does the two year rule means you have to be in your home country, or just outside of UK for two years?
- I put more emphasis on autonomy as a person. Could a Chevening scholarship affect your autonomy in the future (meaning you are obliged to go to gatherings, embassies etc)?

Comment: I'm no lawyer, but I'm pretty sure you could go anywhere you want outside of the UK, although perhaps it might have to be outside of the EU. As for the personal autonomy point, it shouldn't affect that at all. Let me emphasise this point though, I am not a lawyer.